# Как программно взвести флаг, что "документ открыт для редактирования другим пользователем"? 1С Управление торговлей 11.3

Tags: 1с

Знаю, что такой флаг есть у заказов клиента, но не знаю как реализован. Нужно реализовать **программное** взведение такого флага у заказа поставщику. Подскажите в каком направлении копать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так зайду из далека, то что автор вопроса описал называется **объектными блокировкам**и платформы «1С:Предпрятие 8».

**Объектная блокировка** — предназначена для того, чтобы запретить изменение данных определенного объекта другими сеансами или данным сеансом до тех пор, пока блокировка не будет снята этим объектом встроенного языка. Эскалация объектной блокировки невозможна.

Виды объектных блокировок поддерживаемых в системе «1С:Предприятие 8»:
**Пессимистическая блокировка** исходит из предположения, что «если что-то плохое может случиться, это обязательно случится», то есть, если мы выполняем действие, конкурентное выполнение которого может привести к «поломке» данных, то правильным будет исключить возможность конкурентного исполнения. *Простыми словами, если пользователь открыл форму документа в этом случае будет наложена блокировка на изменение этого объекта другими пользователями, **но серверные сеансы могут изменять данные этого объекта**.*

**Оптимистическая блокировка** предполагает, что во время обновления записи в базе мы будем единственными, кто ее меняет. В большинстве случаев, так оно и есть (оптимизм оправдан). Но перед этим необходимо точно удостовериться, что запись с момента ее чтения не изменилась. *Простыми словами при записи изменений объекта необходимо сверится с полем **ВерсияДанных** в базе данных, если версии отличаются будет выдана ошибка.*

Программно можно действительно использовать **Заблокировать()**, но эта блокировка будет держаться только пока длится серверный вызов (выполняется процедура) и защитит только от пользовательских сеансов, *но объект может быть изменен серверным кодом в параллельном сеансе!*

Для более точной рекомендации мне необходима дополнительная информация об бизнес-процессе.

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что приходит в голову — сделать регистр сведений, в который при открытии формы заказа делать запись - какой документ открыт и кем. При открытии формы заказа проверять наличие записи в этом регистре. При закрытии формы удалять соответствующую запись. Единственная проблема - некорректное завершение работы программы, и запись осталась в регистре.

Второй вариант - анализ журнала регистрации.

Comment: Про анализ журнала регистрации можно подробнее?

Comment: Вот как-то так: http://infostart.ru/public/180568/

Comment: Но вообще, если вам не нужно сообщать, кем именно заблокировано, наверное, подойдут методы документа типа Заблокировать() и ЗаблокироватьДанныеДляРедактирования()

Comment: спасибо, попробую так